# how to resolve couldn't match expected type in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
fact :: Int -> Int
fact x = if x == 1 then x else x * fact(x - 1)

nterm :: Double -> Int -> Double
nterm x i =  x ^ i / fromInteger (fact i)

solve :: Double -> Double
solve x = sum [nterm x i| i <- [1..10]] + 1

main :: IO ()
main = getContents >>= mapM_ print. map solve. map (read::String->Double). tail. words
```

I am getting the follwing error while executing the above haskell code. What does this mean ? My understanding is that the type returned by fromInteger (`Integer`) is not same as the type returned by returned by (`Int`).
How can I fix this ?

```
solution.hs:5:35:
    Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `fromInteger', namely `(fact i)'
    In the second argument of `(/)', namely `fromInteger (fact i)'
```

Comment: replace fromInteger with fromIntegral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `fromInteger` with `fromIntegral`.

```
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

It works because `Int` complies with the `Integral` class while `fromInteger` only accepts `Integer` as parameter.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the alternative solution which consists in giving `fact` a more generic type.